# Getting the last word of a line passed to a mapper in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

If I have a dataset with lines like this `199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245` and I am running a map reduce job with hadoop, how can I get the last element in each line?

I have tried all the obvious answers, such as `String lastWord = test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);` but this gives me the `-` character. I have tried splitting it based on a space, and getting the last element, but the last character is still a `-`.

Can I not expect that the data will be delivered to me line by line. In other words, can I not expect a file in the form  `a b c d \n e f g h\n` to be delivered line by line?

And does anyone have any tips on how to get the last word in this line?

This is a snippet from my map function, where I try to get the data:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String test = value.toString();

    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(test);

    //String lastWord = test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(" ")+1); <--first try

    //String [] array = test.split(" ");//<--second try     
    //one.set(Integer.valueOf(array[8])); 

    int i = 0;
    String candidate = null;
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        candidate = tokenizer.nextToken();
        if (i == 3) {
            //this works to get the date field
            String wholeDate = candidate;
            String[] dateArray = wholeDate.split(":");
            String date = dateArray[0].substring(1); // get rid of '['
            String hour = dateArray[1];
            word.set(date + " " + hour);

        } else if (i == 7) { 
                         // <-- third try
             String replySizeString = candidate;
             one.set(Integer.valueOf(replySizeString)); }
        }
        i++;
```

Comment: please post whatever code is being used to generate `test`.

Comment: @DavisBroda I have added updated the post to show all my tries and the creation of `test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a StringTokenizer you could just use the String[] String.split(String regex) method to return an array of Strings for each line.  Then, assuming that each line of your data has the same number of fields, separated by spaces, you can just look at that array element.

```
String line = value.toString();
String[] lineArray = line.split(" ");
String lastWord = lineArray[9];
```

Or if you know that you always want the last token you could see how long the array is and then just grab the last element.

```
String lastWord = lineArray[lineArray.length - 1];
```